# UsersController `User::all()` working but `show` returning `null`

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fetch user based on `id`  but it's returning `null` but `User::all()` is working correctly.

`index` and `show` methods in `UsersController` :-

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth',['except'=>['index','show']]);
}

public function index()
{
    $users=User::all();
    return view('dev.index')->with('users',$users); 
}

public function show(User $user)
{   
    return view('dev.show')->with('user',$user);
}


}
```

Route:-

```
Route::resource('devs','UsersController');
```

On view I have `{{dd($user->name)}}` and it's returning `null` on url `public/devs/{dev}`.

but working fine on `index` on url `public/devs`

Comment: If you change the route path to `'users'` work? I think this is the origin of the issue (Model Binding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are defining your base route like this:

```php
Route::resource('devs', 'UserController');
```

This means that laravel will format the `show` method as follows:

```php
Route::get('devs/{dev}', 'UserController@show');
```

Laravel will try to solve this dependency doind [Implicit Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#implicit-binding) and given that `{dev}` doesn't match any of your defined model classes, it will indeed return `null`.

So to solve it, define this match explicitly doing [Explicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#explicit-binding). To accomplish this, go to your:

**App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('dev', App\User::class);
}
```

So now wherever Laravel reads the `{dev}` route parameter, will match it with the `User` model.

Comment: The other easy option is to rename the parameter: `show(User $dev) {}`

Comment: @TravisBritz I haven't tried that approach tho, but if its valid, of course it can be a nice work-around. Have a good day.

Comment: @HCK it's giving an error right now but I will try to fix them and if it worked, I will use that method cuz it looks like a better approach. Thanks

Comment: @HCK I upvoted for your explanation, but one small correction: route model binding only looks for matching route variable and parameter names. As long as the variable name matches  (and the type-hint is a model) it will be able to bind correctly

Comment: @HCK it's working now but I had to remove `parent::boot();` and import `use App` `use Route` and now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize users for your entire controller.
Each function uses their own variables

First of all, I would reconfigure your route like so:

```
Route::get('devs', 'UsersController@show')->name('showUsers')
```

In your function show I would do the following

```
public static function show(){
   $id = 1;
   $users = User::where('id', $id')
   return view('dev.show', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: An edit was rejected for this answer: suggested adding `->first()` or `->get()` to the end of `$users = User::where(...);`; converts query builder into a User or Collection of User models. Also, you have a typo; `$id'`, extra `'`.